# Jquery-picklist.js does not allow access to target list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, picklist

I am using jquery-picklist.js in my form. I have select option with id basic like this :-

```
select id="basic" name="basic" multiple="multiple"
```

To create picklist I have to add this in my js file

```
$("#basic").pickList();
```

But how do I access the target side of my picklist? I cannot access through basic variable since it gives me source side :-

```
selectedPROC = InvForm.basic_pickList_targetList;
```

Even above line does not work .Any solutions?